# how to call javascript from asp.net HyperLink control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, hyperlink

I simply want to call a JavaScript function from asp.net hyperlink
im using http://orangoo.com/labs/GreyBox/ my requirement is to show thumbnail on hyperlink and on click show full image. Should I use another control?
my code is below:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="Hyperlink" runat="server" CssClass="Screenshot" ImageUrl="App_Themes/White/Images/thmb_screenshot_1.png"
                        NavigateUrl="App_Themes/White/Images/screenshot_1.png" ToolTip="screenshot 1"   />   

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">     
    //Greybox Image popup window
    function OpenImage(url) {
        var caption = "Home";
        return GB_showImage(caption, url)
    }         
</script>
```

how can I use

```
onclick="OpenImage(this.src);
or 
OnClientClick="OpenImage(this.src);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use a `LinkButton` instead, you can use the `OnClientClick` property to execute a JavaScript function. Using the `HyperLink` control, you can use the `NavigateUrl` property like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="Link1" runat="server"
    Text="Click Me!"
    NavigateUrl="javascript:OpenImage('App_Themes/White/Images/thmb_screenshot_1.png');">
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Here's an article that discusses it:
http://gchandra.wordpress.com/2007/09/27/call-javascript-function-inside/

Answer (score 13):

I know this is old but to anyone interested, just add onclick and it will work fine. The extra attribute (even though it doesn't show up on intellisense) will pass through to the rendered markup.

```
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" onclick="logDownload();" NavigateUrl="~/download/Sample-Icons.zip">Download Icons</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Just replace OnClientClick on OnClick — standart HTML attribute. As mentioned below, there is no OnClientClick property in HyperLink class.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but for anyone looking to do this on the server side and not through the markup, you can do.

```
var hyperLink = new HyperLink { Text = "Display text", ID = "hyperlinkId"};
hyperLink.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascriptMethod()");
```

Answer (score -4):

It looks like you are basically there, what's wrong with this?

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="Hyperlink" runat="server" OnClientClick="OpenImage(this.src)" />
```

Comment: its not showing  the onclick or onclientclick Property in intellisense

Comment: That doesn't matter, it will work anyway. WebForms will render attributes that it doesn't recognise into html for you.

Comment: <asp:HyperLink ID="Hyperlink" runat="server" OnClientClick="OpenImage(this.src)" />   
it doesnt work

Comment: this worked for me
 <img src="App_Themes/White/Images/thmb_screenshot_1.png" onclick="OpenImage('ScreenShot 1','../../App_Themes/White/Images/screenshot_1.png');" />

Comment: There is no `OnClientClick` attribute for the HyperLink control.

Comment: @ilivewithian while you are correct Webforms will render attributes it doesn't recognize, you would need to do OnClick, not OnClientClick, because on the client side it is OnClick.